In Rust, how to write a generic function that accepts iterator of a reference to a trait?
I want to implement a function that accepts an iterator to a trait.
trait A
{
    fn f(&self);
}

fn foo<It>(it: It)
where
    It: Iterator,
    It::Item: A
{
    it.for_each(|x| x.f());
}

This works if I move an object into the function:
let aa = vec![...]; // it has some objects that implement A
foo(aa.into_iter());

However, if I don't want to move out my container, then it won't work, because the compiler complains that &Something doesn't implement A.
foo(aa.iter());

I could just accept a slice.
fn foo(aa: &[impl A]) { ... }

But then it would only work if I pass it a simple container, but not if I want something more complicated like this:
foo(bars.iter().map(|bar| bar.a));


Why don't you add a blanket impl<T: A> A for &T? That's probably the simplest solution if you can get away with it.

A is not mine, it comes from a library. Besides, I'm pretty sure it's not an idiomatic way to do it.

Implementing traits for &T is fairly idiomatic if all the trait methods take &self. See impl Display for &T in the standard library as a quick example.

Introduce another generic type parameter T so that the constraints that the iterator Item is &T and that T implements A can be defined separately:
fn foo<'a, T: 'a, It>(it: It)
where
    It: Iterator<Item = &'a T>,
    T: A,
{
    it.for_each(|x| x.f());
}


That might work if I only wanted to use it with a reference. Is it possible to make it work for both iter() and into_iter()?

@petersohn you can replace &'a T with std::borrow::Borrow<T> but you have to call .borrow() on every x before you can call .f(). It's probably also a good idea to use IntoIterator over Iterator to be able to also pass collections directly.

Using Borrow is an option to accept owned or referenced values, however I'd be hesitant to suggest it here since then the compiler wouldn't be able to deduce what T is without an explicit type annotation.
